# Error al ejecutar Cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql

Cuando ejecuto el siguiente bloque SQL, me dice que debo declarar la variable p_nombre, pero yo la he declarado antes.

```
declare
p_nombre varchar2(200) ;
BEGIN

    FOR REG IN (select c1000 INTO p_nombre 
        from edyficar.cl_clientes2 
        where cod_seg_mor = 1 and cod_seg_cob = 9 and c8421 = 'S' and segmentacion = 'C1' )
    LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line(REG.p_nombre);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con:

```
DECLARE
CURSOR cursor_nombre is 
    select c1000 
    from edyficar.cl_clientes2 
    where cod_seg_mor = 1 
    and cod_seg_cob = 9 
    and c8421 = 'S' 
    and segmentacion = 'C1';
BEGIN
    FOR REG IN cursor_nombre
    LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line(REG.c1000);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Hola Carlos, bienvenido. Las respuestas provistas solo de código no se consideran de buena calidad. Te sugiero que añadas una explicación de qué tiene mal el autor de la pregunta y como tu codigo lo soluciona. Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

El error se debe a `reg.p_nombre` que no has declarado. En realidad, el problema es que estás tratando de usar la sintaxis de cursores implícitos (muy bien), pero mezclándolo con la sintaxis del `SELECT ... INTO` (mal).

La forma correcta de usar los cursores implícitos es la siguiente (nota que de la forma correcta, ni siquiera necesitas declarar la variable `p_nombre`:

```
BEGIN
    FOR REG IN (select c1000
        from edyficar.cl_clientes2 
        where cod_seg_mor = 1 and cod_seg_cob = 9 and c8421 = 'S' and segmentacion = 'C1' )
    LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line(REG.c1000);
    END LOOP;
END;
```